# dropzone js empty send empty post data

Tags: php, forms, file, dropzone.js

This is the form:

```
<form id="upload" action="envia_consulta.php" method="post" class="consulta" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="denominacion">Nombre / persona de contacto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Escriba su nombre o el nombre de la persona de contacto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="denominacion">Teléfono</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Escriba su número de teléfono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="denominacion">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Escriba su dirección de email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="descripcion">Consulta</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="consulta" name="consulta" placeholder="Escriba su consulta"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Adjuntar archivo/s</label>
        <div id="drop" class="dropzone dz-clickable dropzone-previews">
           <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>ARRASTRE LOS ARCHIVOS AQUÍ O PULSE PARA BUSCAR</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox terminos">
        <label>
            <input name="acepto" value="S" type="checkbox">  Acepto las <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#condiciones" href="#no">Condiciones de uso</a> y <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#politica" href="#no">Política de Protección de datos</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="fallo_validacion alert alert-danger" style="display:none" role="alert"></div>
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none;margin-top:30px;"><strong>¡Gracias!</strong> Hemos recibido su consulta. En breve le responderemos. </div>
    <div>
        <input id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar consulta">
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
Dropzone.options.drop = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
    // The configuration we've talked about above
    url: 'envia_consulta.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;


        // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
        $('#enviar').on("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            //alert('aa');

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            if (myDropzone.files.length !== 0) {
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            // Else just submit the form and move on.
            } else {
                $('.consulta').submit();
            }
        });

        this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {

            alert('sendin multiple');
            //$('.consulta').submit();
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
            alert('succes multiple');

            alert(response);

        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
            alert('error multiple');
        });
    }
}
```

I have a mixed form (files and data), when I submitting the form without data, the server side `$_post` is not empty, but when I submit data and files, the `$_files` variable contains de files uploaded, but `$_post` variable is empty.  See the dropzone example: [here](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone), but in my case it does not work.

Any solutions?